# Why is $I_0\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\omega t\right)$ not used as a solution of the purely capacitive AC circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance

Why is $I_0\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\omega t\right)$ not used as a solution of the purely capacitive circuit?

**My Research**

I've searched on Google, Phys.SE and many school level Physics books but couldn't find the answer. If the reader thinks that the question can be answered with a quick google search then please give me that link.

Comment: Your solution is just $I_0\cos(\omega t)$, what's the problem?

Comment: @JamalS The problem is: Why $I_0sin(\fracπ2−ωt)$ is not used as a solution of the purely capacitive circuit?

Comment: Aside from a sign difference, take a look at http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/ac-capacitance.html

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Both the links don't give the answer of my question.

Comment: I guess what's missing from this question is this: why do you think (e.g. who says) that $I_0\sin(\pi/2-\omega t)$ isn't used as a solution, and why do you think it should be?

Comment: Maybe because it's just a more complicated way of writing a $\cos$?

Comment: @Ruslan I find $\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\omega t)$ as much complicated as $\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\omega t)$.

Comment: @user31782 as people have pointed out in the edit summaries, "thanks" statements and the like should not be in questions or answers. Please don't roll back that change again. Keep in mind that the edits other people are making to your question are to improve it.

Comment: @DavidZ I do not abide by the policies of this website. Until I'm human I'll keep saying thanks to those who would help me.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can use  $I_0\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\omega t)$  equally well as a solution of a purely capacitive AC circuit, as can be the others. The essence lies in the fact, that in an AC circuit, the voltage behaviour is "sinusoidal". Then you ask, what do I mean by the term "sinusoidal".

A general sinusoidal curve is as given below:

[image]

**The horizontal axis defines (angular-frequency x time)**

**The vertical axis defines voltage-drop across capacitor.**

See that, I have drawn no vertical axis. The vertical axis is given, only at the time, the observation is started. This vertical axis defines our t=0, and depending on where we place this vertical axis on the plane, we would get different equations for the alternating voltage drop, across the capacitor.[image]

As you can see, this voltage behaviour is governed by the equation $V_0\sin(\omega t)$. Now look below:

[image]

This voltage behaviour is governed by the equation: $-V_0\sin(\omega t)$. This, is the same as $V_0\sin(-\omega t)$ .

Now, for a purely capacitive AC circuit, current leads voltage-drop by a phase angle of $(\dfrac{\pi}{2})$ radians. So,

$I=$$I_0\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\omega t)$ is **indeed** a solution for current, for a purely capacitive AC circuit, when voltage-drop across capacitor, behaves as shown in the 3rd diagram.

I too had the same problem of "which equation should it be" while studying wave-motion.